# Redis key is always flushed in ~150 seconds with and without setting expire

Tags: redis, centos, redis-server

I installed redis-server on my Centos and figured out that any key I set in my PHP or redis-cli - it's being deleted after 150 seconds. Have no idea what to do with it. Everywhere I see that redis keys have no TTL, but in my case it seems like somewhere is set global redis TTL. Any ideas why keys can be removed in 150 seconds?

Comment: Can you please post your redis configuration files.

Comment: It's totally default as this one http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf. It's so odd thing happening.

Comment: can you give some more info: Redis version, check uptime of Redis(check if it is getting restarted), all keys are getting deleted?, post `info` command output

Comment: So sorry. Found out that the neighbour website stored next to mine is flushing Redis cache on Cron schedule every 2 minutes. Created another Redis instance with different port and solved the problem.